# word count frequency except punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the 20 words that appear most frequently in the dataset, except for punctuation. So far the code I have tried is

```
dataset['token'].value_counts()[:20]
```

output :

```
,          88144
.          49109
dan        37283
di         33701
yang       29353
-LRB-      19843
-RRB-      19736
''         15906
``         15232
dengan     15231
pada       15021
dari       14900
tahun      13079
sebagai     9038
ini         8371
untuk       8297
dalam       8266
adalah      7950
menjadi     7414
oleh        5974
```

but there are still punctuation marks. how to do it so that the highest word frequency does not include the punctuation?
Thanks..

Comment: Remove all the punctuation from the text before counting the words?

Comment: Can you specify your expected output? Or we can assume that, only values with punctuation marks should not be counted?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do word preprocessing before counting then. Example :

```
import pandas as pd
import re

REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')

def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text)
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text)
    
    return text

ft = pd.read_json(path_of_file) # read ur file in pandas df
ft = ft.apply(clean_text)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

A pure Python solution.

1. Remove everything but word characters from the text
2. Give all the words to a `Counter`
3. Ask for the 20 most common.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_most_common(text, n=20):
    processed_text = "".join(t for t in text.lower() if t.isalpha() or t == " ")
    counter = Counter(processed_text.split())
    return counter.most_common(n)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

Assuming you are not interested in only punctuation values. If there is both punctuation and words, it would be counted.

```
dataset['token'][dataset['token'].str.contains(r'\w+')].value_counts()[:20]
```